# Pyinstaller error: No module named 'yaml'

Tags: pyinstaller

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 101, in \<module\>
File "main.py", line 97, in main
File "video_processing.py", line 140, in video_processing
File "torch\\hub.py", line 542, in load
model = \_load_local(repo_or_dir, model, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "torch\\hub.py", line 572, in \_load_local
model = entry(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "../yolov5/hubconf.py", line 83, in custom
return \_create(path, autoshape=autoshape, verbose=\_verbose, device=device)
File "../yolov5/hubconf.py", line 33, in \_create
from models.common import AutoShape, DetectMultiBackend
File "../yolov5\\models\\common.py", line 29, in \<module\>
from utils.dataloaders import exif_transpose, letterbox
File "../yolov5\\utils\\dataloaders.py", line 26, in \<module\>
import yaml`
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yaml'
```

I was compiling my codes to .exe, however when I run the exe, it popped up this error message.
I have already installed pyyaml on my computer, I don't know why it didn't compiled into the exe? I tried "--hidden-import pyyaml", still not working,
I tried "-p c:\users\abc\python37\lib\site-package",not working

Answer (score 0):

you can't use Pyinstaller for projects with Pyyaml. You can find all supported packages on this page: [Supported packages](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages)